# can chef display a message during executions

Tags: chef-infra

can chef display a message during executions. Taken help from this link but not getting a proper solutions 
https://docs.chef.io/resource_log.html
http://sysadvent.blogspot.in/2012/12/day-24-twelve-things-you-didnt-know.html

Comment: What do you wish to do ? We can't do divination of your use case...

Answer (score 1):

Chef already displays many messages during execution. If you wanted to display something specific, you could put `Chef::Log.warn('hello world')` to log display a message during compilation, or use a [log resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_log.html) to display a message during convergence.

Comment: Maybe you can say a word on how they act differently (compile time for Chef::Log vs converge time for log resource)